# SharpDX Texture2D from DataStream

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I want to show one of my WPF applications in VR and ran into a little problem when rendering the overlay texture directly from a datastream. The texture isn´t displaye correctly.

First of all I render my WPF Application into a Bitmap and save it to a stream:

```
      RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)visual.ActualWidth, (int)visual.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bitmap.Render(visual);
        BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
        encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
        m_vrStream.Position = 0;
        encoder.Save(m_vrStream);
```

I don´t want to use Unity for the VR part so I switched to SharpDX and created a new Texture2D.

```
 var description2D = new Texture2DDescription()
 {
    Width = 1920,
    Height = 1080,
    ArraySize = 1,
    MipLevels = 1,
    Format = SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
    SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
 };

 m_texture = new Texture2D(m_device, description2D, new[] { new SharpDX.DataBox(m_dataStream.DataPointer,description2D.Width
            * (int)FormatHelper.SizeOfInBytes(description2D.Format),0)});
```

This always brings a System.AccessViolationException. If I lower the width and height in Texture2DDescription, the texture is displayed but not correctly (random colored pixel). 
If I first save the datastream into a .png file and load it with

```
m_texture = TextureLoader.CreateTexture2DFromBitmap(m_device, TextureLoader.LoadBitmap(new SharpDX.WIC.ImagingFactory2(), "test.png"));
```

everything looks fine.

I´m new to graphics programming and believe that I have a miss understanding in the Texture2DDescription part. The width and height are hard coded for testing purposes and fitting the size of the image I´m generating

Hope someone can give me some hints with that.

Thanks and regards